# Pointer being freed not allocated (Remove duplicates from unsorted linked list - c++)

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, hashtable

I'm trying to figure out an implementation for the following question:

**Remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list.**

My approach was to try to iterate through the linked list.  At each node, check the hash table to see if it exists.  If it does, delete the node.  Otherwise, insert to the list.

My linked list implementation:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node *next;
    Node(int d){data = d;}
};

class LinkedList {
private:
    Node *head;
public:
    LinkedList() {head = NULL;}
    ~LinkedList() {
        while (head != NULL) {
            Node *tmp = head;
            head = head->next;
            delete tmp;
        }
    }
    void add(int d) {
        Node *newNode = new Node(d);
        newNode->next = head;
        head = newNode;
    }
    void print() {
        Node *cur = head;
        while (cur != NULL) {
            std::cout << cur->data << "->";
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
    Node *getHead() {
        return head;
    }
};
```

Hash Table:

```
class HashNode {
protected:
    int key;
    int value;
    HashNode *next;
public:
    HashNode(int key, int value) {
        this->key = key;
        this->value = value;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
    friend class HashMap;
};

class HashMap {
private:
    HashNode **htable;
public:
    HashMap() {
        htable = new HashNode*[tableSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
            htable[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    ~HashMap() {
        for (int i = 0; i < tableSize; i++) {
            HashNode *entry = htable[i];
            while (entry != NULL) {
                HashNode *prev = entry;
                entry = entry->next;
                delete prev;
            }
            delete[] htable;
        }
    }
    int hashFunction(int key) {
        return key % tableSize;
    }
    void insert(int key, int value) {
        int hashVal = hashFunction(key);
        HashNode *prev = NULL;
        HashNode *entry = htable[hashVal];
        while (entry != NULL) {
            prev = entry;
            entry = entry->next;
        }
        entry = new HashNode(key, value);
        if (prev == NULL) {
            htable[hashVal] = entry;
        } else {
            prev->next = entry;
        }
    }
    bool search(int key) {
        bool flag = false;
        int hashVal = hashFunction(key);
        HashNode *entry = htable[hashVal];
        while (entry != NULL) {
            if (entry->key == key)
                flag = true;
            entry = entry->next;
        }
        return flag;
    }
};
```

and finally my function to remove duplicates:

```
void removeDuplicates(LinkedList *listPtr, HashMap *hashPtr) {
    Node *cur = listPtr->getHead();
    Node *prev = NULL;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        Node *tmp = cur;
        if (hashPtr->search(cur->data)) {
            prev->next = cur->next;
            cur = cur->next;
            delete tmp;
        } else {
            hashPtr->insert(cur->data, 1);
            prev = cur;
            cur = cur->next;
        }
    }
}
```

when I run the following in main:

```
#include <iostream>
const int tablesize = 128;
int main() {
    LinkedList myList;
    HashMap intMap;
    myList.add(1);
    myList.add(3);
    myList.add(5);
    myList.add(3);
    myList.add(3);
    myList.add(5);
    myList.add(20);
    myList.add(57);
    std::cout << "before function call: \n";
    myList.print();
    removeDuplicates(&myList, &intMap);
    std::cout << "\nafter:\n";
    myList.print();

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output I get:

```
before function call: 
57->20->5->3->3->5->3->1->
after:
go(14453,0x7fff762c1300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7f9250801200: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
57->20->5->3->1->Abort trap: 6
```

The final list is printing out correctly, but I am still getting the weird error associated with it.
Can anybody help me out and give a newbie some tips to what I am doing wrong, thanks in advance.

Edit - I ran it under gdb and this was the output:

```
main () at 2.1RemoveDuplicatesFromLinkedList.cpp:149
149     std::cout << "\nafter:\n";
(gdb) step
57->20->5->3->3->5->3->1->
after:
150     myList.print();
(gdb) step
152     return 0;
(gdb) step
broken(14784,0x7fff762c1300) malloc: *** error for object 0x100801200: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
57->20->5->3->1->
Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
0x00007fff8484e286 in __pthread_kill () from /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
(gdb)
```

Oddly, I was curious so I went and compiled and executed at cpp.sh online.  The output was exactly as expected and program terminated without any errors.  Any ideas of what could be causing this on my local machine? (OS X)

Comment: This is on the borderline for being too much code in a single question.

Comment: Can you run under a debugger and check where exactly that error is occurring, please?

Comment: What do you think will happen when you `delete cur/tmp` and then do `cur = cur->next`?

Comment: @user657267 I updated the code and works a little bit better but still giving an error can you take a look? thanks

Comment: Please run under a debugger; you are (I think) accessing memory you do not own, and your debugger will tell you much faster than we can.

Comment: @KenY-N OK I will do, thanks for your reply

Comment: There are three separate problems here: how to implement a linked list, how to implement a hash map and how to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list. I suggest you solve and test each one separately and in order. If you are only interested in the final algorithm, why not use the standard list and hash map (`std::unordered_map` or even `std::map` will do for a prototype)?

Comment: @KenY-N I ran under the gdb debugger, added it to the post.  Its strange, I went and compiled online and it worked exactly as expected.  is something wrong with my system?

Comment: @JohnDoe You're deleting `htable` on every loop iteration inside `~HashMap()`, move `delete[] htable;` outside the loop.

Comment: @user657267 thank you